# Is NSWindow setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel broken in OS X 10.6.x

Tags: macos, nswindow

We're trying to get a NSWindow or NSPanel to be always on top on OS X 10.6.x. We've seen many suggestions that setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel should do the trick (some say it must be a NSPanel for it to stay on top).

However, we are using 10.6.4. and the window keeps disappearing to the background when the app looses focus.

I've seen one report that Apple has dropped this possibility from the OS alltogether.

Can somebody tell me if setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel should still work?

ANY working example code for 10.6 would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Bart

Answer (score 4):

Note to self: if you set the 'Hide on Deactivate' of a window to true, the windows will disappear (and thus not be on top :-().

So, setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel simply still works.

Comment: My mistake was calling `setLevel` in my view controller's `viewDidLoad` instead of its `viewDidAppear`.